# Where can I get the Packager for iPhone binary for Adobe AIR?

Tags: ios, air, pfi

I need to package an AIR app for older iOS devices. To do this I apparently need the Packager for iPhone tool, which is not available from Adobe Labs anymore and isn't included in the archived version of AIR 2.0.2. Can someone point me to a copy?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment at least, PC version is available [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flash/updates/11/ios/win/PFI_WIN_2_0_1_12640.zip).

Mac version is [here](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flash/updates/11/ios/mac/PFI_MAC_2_0_1_12640.zip).